# lualatex issue after TL2022 upgrade

Tags: luatex, texlive

So my upgrade of TL2022 didn't go without a hitch.  When I compile a document with lualatex, I get the following strange errors:

```
warning  (nodes): attempt to copy free vlist node 8648, ignored
warning  (nodes): attempt to copy free vlist node 8779, ignored
warning  (nodes): attempt to copy free hlist node 8607, ignored
warning  (nodes): attempt to copy free hlist node 8616, ignored
warning  (nodes): attempt to copy free vlist node 8875, ignored
warning  (nodes): attempt to copy free hlist node 8884, ignored
```

(and more) and there's no resulting PDF.  The last error is:

```
error:  (pdf backend): no vlist or hlist in (xform) shipout
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!%
```

What do I need to do to get lualatex working again?  For definiteness, my test documents compile fine with pdflatex and xelatex.

Comment: @Mico I've been on this site long enough to know when to post a MWE! I judged it not helpful here because it felt like a problem with my installation not with a document so posting a MWE wouldn't help.  Indeed, thanks to Ulrike's suggestion on my other question it was a problem with the formats not being re-compiled during my installation.  I've now run `fmtutil-sys --all` and the problem is solved.  This is probably now `too localised` but it might be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be due to the same problem as on my question [expl3.sty date mismatch after TL update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662487/expl3-sty-date-mismatch-after-tl-update?noredirect=1#comment1647856_662487), namely that the formats hadn't been rebuilt during the installation.

I had to manually run `fmtutil-sys --all` and that fixed the problem.